# OK to run SVN and Mercurial on the same Windows 7 PC (along with Tortoise SVN & Hg?)

Tags: mercurial, tortoisesvn, windows-7-x64, tortoisehg

Is this OK to do?

I have one folder that is a checkout of SVN, another that is Hg.

But Windows Explorer is crashing now when I right click a file in the Hg folder.
I uninstalled Hg and then I could right click without a crash.
Reinstalled and crashes came back.

Comment: I have TSVN, TGit and THg installed and Explorer works fine. Which THg version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's OK. You *may* have some troubles (but not crashing of Explorer) in case of using *different* icon-overlays in THG and TSVN (due to limiting amount of overlays to rather small amount)